# Установка xslt парсера

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xml, xslt

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить xslt парсер на ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: как вы его собираетесь использовать?

Comment: html, css, js - разрабатывать электронные формы отчетности

Comment: а можете чуть подробнее? Это какая-то программа? Или вы собираетесь этот парсер на прямую использовать?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, в Ubuntu при установке уже имеется парсер XSLT - он используется рабочим окружением GNOME или KDE. Но чтобы написать свою программу с его применением, вам придётся установить пакет с файлами для разработки.

Пакет называется **libxslt1-dev**. Установите его вашим любимым менеджером пакетов и скомпилируйте демонстрационный пример.

```
gcc libxslt_tutorial.c `pkg-config libxslt --libs --cflags`
```

Содержимое файла libxslt_tutorial.c можно найти в документации.

http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/tutorial/libxslttutorial.html

Comment: На самом деле это только один из вариантов. Я на 146% уверен, что есть библиотека, написанная на JS, как раз для этих целей.